# Cannot find package '@/babel' imported from

Tags: babel

Cuando ejecuto el script build me aparece el error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@/babel' imported from C:\Users\edwin\Documents\webpack\js-portfolio\babel-virtual-resolve-base.js
    at new NodeError (C:\Users\edwin\Documents\webpack\js-portfolio\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\vendor\import-meta-resolve.js:2552:5)
    at packageResolve (C:\Users\edwin\Documents\webpack\js-portfolio\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\vendor\import-meta-resolve.js:3208:9)
    at moduleResolve (C:\Users\edwin\Documents\webpack\js-portfolio\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\vendor\import-meta-resolve.js:3242:18)
    at defaultResolve (C:\Users\edwin\Documents\webpack\js-portfolio\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\vendor\import-meta-resolve.js:3281:13)
    at C:\Users\edwin\Documents\webpack\js-portfolio\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\vendor\import-meta-resolve.js:3304:14
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at asyncGeneratorStep (C:\Users\edwin\Documents\webpack\js-portfolio\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\vendor\import-meta-resolve.js:63:103)
    at _next (C:\Users\edwin\Documents\webpack\js-portfolio\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\vendor\import-meta-resolve.js:65:194)
    at C:\Users\edwin\Documents\webpack\js-portfolio\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\vendor\import-meta-resolve.js:65:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)

webpack 5.70.0 compiled with 1 error in 2604 ms
```

En mi package json me asegure de instalar todas las dependencias, trate de eliminar la carpeta node_modules y volver a instalar y tampoco funcionó

esta es mi configuracion de webpack:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.m?js$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: {
                        loader: "babel-loader"
                    }
                }
            ]
    }
}
```